# Why am I getting the exception "System.StackOverflowException"?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code. The code gets me some values from a table , table contents , some textboxes and other , things. When I am click button the submit button, I get a value and put in "st" (type class student) and put in the database. But it is showing me an exception in list attributes " **get** {....}" the exception "System.StackOverflowException"

```
     public StudentManager()
            : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["con"].ConnectionString)
    {

    }
        public override void Add(Student entity)
        {
           //add to database 
        }

        protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Student st = new Student();
            st.id = Convert.ToInt32(IdTextBox.Text);
            st.AVG = Convert.ToDouble(AVGTextBox.Text);
            st.date = dateCalendar.TodaysDate;
            st.educationInfo = educationInfoTextBox.Text;
            faculty fa = new faculty();
            fa.id = Convert.ToInt32(facultyDropDownList.SelectedValue);
            st.faculty = fa;
            st.fatherName = fatherNameTextBox.Text;
            st.fName = fNameTextBox.Text;
            st.lName = lNameTextBox.Text;
            st.motherName = motherNameTextBox.Text;
            st.password = passwordTextBox.Text;
            st.personalInfo = personalInfoTextBox.Text;
            StudentManager sm = new StudentManager();
            sm.Add(st);
        }
 public class Student 
    {
        public int id { get; set; }

        public faculty faculty { get; set; }
        public double AVG { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public string educationInfo { get; set; }
        public string fatherName { get; set; }
        public string fName { get; set; }
        public string lName { get; set; }
        public string motherName { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
        public string personalInfo { get; set; }
        private List<SqlParameter> Attributes;
        public List<SqlParameter> attributes
        {
            get
            {
                Attributes = new List<SqlParameter>();
                SqlParameter sp = new SqlParameter();
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("id",this.id));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("faculty", this.faculty));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("AVG", this.AVG));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("date", date));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("educationInfo",educationInfo));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("fatherName", fatherName));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("lName", lName));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("motherName", motherName));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("password", password));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("personalInfo", personalInfo));
                return Attributes;
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Note that by convention properties start with an upper case letter and fields start with a lower case letter.

Comment: Are you intending to call `Attributes.Add` instead of `attributes.Add` in your "getter"?

Comment: @SamIam Well, that would be quite odd, to have a getter that mutated a list like that...

Comment: Since you are using Visual Studio the exception message pretty much tells you everything you need to know why this is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the property in you class makes recursive calls.

```
public List<SqlParameter> attributes
        {
            get
            {
                Attributes = new List<SqlParameter>();
                SqlParameter sp = new SqlParameter();
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("id",this.id));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("faculty", this.faculty));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("AVG", this.AVG));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("date", date));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("educationInfo",educationInfo));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("fatherName", fatherName));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("lName", lName));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("motherName", motherName));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("password", password));
                attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("personalInfo", personalInfo));
                return Attributes;
            }
```

To resolve this I feel it would be better to convert it to a method instead of using a property.  It can be done like this:

```
public List<SqlParameter> GetAttributes()
{
    //replace your code here to get attributes
    List<SqlParameter> attributes = new List<SqlParameter>();
    SqlParameter sp = new SqlParameter();
    attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("id", this.id));
    attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("faculty", this.faculty));
    attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("AVG", this.AVG));
    attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("date", date));
    attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("educationInfo", educationInfo));
    attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("fatherName", fatherName));
    attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("lName", lName));
    attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("motherName", motherName));
    attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("password", password));
    attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("personalInfo", personalInfo));
    return attributes;
}
```

Remove `private List<SqlParameter> Attributes;` from your code

Comment: that's quite an interesting "getter"

Comment: converting it to a method isn't really the solution; he just needs to not call itself recursively...

Comment: @Servy - i given my implementation way...hop you like it

Comment: @Servy - i think as per me its better to a method instead of property

Answer (score 3):

Your `attributes_Get` method is calling itself recursively.

Change it to:

```
    // this should be a Get() method, not a property.
    public List<SqlParameter> GetAttributes()
    {
        attributes = new List<SqlParameter>();
        SqlParameter sp = new SqlParameter();
        attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("id",this.id));
        attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("faculty", this.faculty));
        attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("AVG", this.AVG));
        attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("date", date));
        attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("educationInfo",educationInfo));
        attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("fatherName", fatherName));
        attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("lName", lName));
        attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("motherName", motherName));
        attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("password", password));
        attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("personalInfo", personalInfo));
        return attributes;
    }
```

Comment: He'll also need to change the field as well, or make `attributes` a local.

Comment: Oh, and you shouldn't add the `Get` prefix to a property; it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @Servy agreed - I just forgot to add the parens :)

Comment: If you make it a method it shouldn't have `get { ... `  That needs to go away.

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe one of these days SO will have intellisense and syntax highlighting :)

Answer (score 0):

because when your code call this property:

```
    public List<SqlParameter> attributes
    {
        get
        {
            Attributes = new List<SqlParameter>();
            SqlParameter sp = new SqlParameter();
            attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("id",this.id));
            attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("faculty", this.faculty));
            attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("AVG", this.AVG));
            attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("date", date));
            attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("educationInfo",educationInfo));
            attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("fatherName", fatherName));
            attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("lName", lName));
            attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("motherName", motherName));
            attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("password", password));
            attributes.Add(new SqlParameter("personalInfo", personalInfo));
            return Attributes;
        }

    }
```

and it reaches `attributes.Add()` lines it again call this property which make a recursive call so use another variable name ie,

```
    public List<SqlParameter> attributes
    {
        get
        {
            var myAttributes= new List<SqlParameter>();
            SqlParameter sp = new SqlParameter();
            myAttributes.Add(new SqlParameter("id",this.id));
            myAttributes.Add(new SqlParameter("faculty", this.faculty));
            myAttributes.Add(new SqlParameter("AVG", this.AVG));
            myAttributes.Add(new SqlParameter("date", date));
            myAttributes.Add(new SqlParameter("educationInfo",educationInfo));
            myAttributes.Add(new SqlParameter("fatherName", fatherName));
            myAttributes.Add(new SqlParameter("lName", lName));
            myAttributes.Add(new SqlParameter("motherName", motherName));
            myAttributes.Add(new SqlParameter("password", password));
            myAttributes.Add(new SqlParameter("personalInfo", personalInfo));
            return myAttributes;
        }

    }
```